# Как запустить графическую программу 24/7 на VPS

Tags: java, сервер, vps

У меня есть VPS с FTP доступом. Ubuntu Server. У меня есть .jar программа. Мне надо, чтобы она работала постоянно. Я запускал её через X11, но стоит мне закрыть окошко на компе, как программа закрывается. Что делать?

Comment: Установите https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb, потом запустите его командой типа `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24` потом `export DISPLAY=:1` и java программа с графикой после этого должна работать.

Comment: @RomanKonoval можно подробности?

Comment: Вроде бы, если при запуске в консоли в конце команды запуска поставит пробел и амерсанд, то программа не завершится, если закрыть терминал

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но завершается, если я закрою программу через X11